# Adding a border to PDF from ArcMap export using Arcpy

Tags: python, border, gis, arcgis, arcpy

I'm trying to add a border to a PDF exported from ArcMap, using arcpy.  I've not been able to find the answer to this anywhere, nor does arcpy seem to have any documentation on this.

Oddly enough, the map layout from which I'm exporting already has a black border around it, but when I export to a PDF, there is no border.  My code here:

```
#Export to PDF
currentMXD_Map = (r"myMap.mxd")
mxd_Map = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(currentMXD_Map)
df_Map = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd_Map,"*")[0]
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd_Map, r"myMap.pdf", df_Map,
                          df_export_width=3300,
                          df_export_height=2550)
        
mxd_Map.save()
```

I would think arcpy.mapping has a method to add border to a PDF export (or in the map layout). What can I try next?

Comment: I think this would quickly be answered if asked at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

arcpy is not designed for map or layout authoring. It is designed to manipulate existing layouts or maps. Here's a quote from the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/analyze/arcpy-mapping/guidelinesforarcpymapping.htm)

> The arcpy.mapping module was designed so that it can be used to modify
>   existing elements within already existing map documents (.mxd) or
>   layer files (.lyr). In other words, it helps with the automation of
>   existing features but it can't be used to author new objects.

The easiest way to "add" a border is to have a border already in your map layout with size set to 0 or positioned off screen and then to use arcpy to make it visible or move it where you want. It seems you already have the border so maybe it's not in the right place or is set to 0 width.

Either way, you can access the border element by giving it a name in arcmap and then accessing with ListLayoutElements.

First fill in the "Element Name" in the elements properties in arcmap. notice how I've set the height and width to 0 so that it won't be visible normally.

[image]

Then access the element with [ListLayoutElements](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listlayoutelements.htm)

```
#we want the first border element because we are assuming there is only one.
#iterate or change index depending on your scenario
borderElement = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "GRAPHIC_ELEMENT", "border_element")[0]
borderElement.elementHeight = y
borderElement.elementWidth = x
```

Comment: Thanks - but isn't this setting the element width and height, not the border width?

Comment: yes it's setting the element width and height. Not sure if the border width is exposed via arcpy.